# JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException while executing flyway migration script in h2 on spring-boot startup

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, h2

I use an H2 db for development locally for my spring-boot application along with Flyway. I have a flyway migration script that has some MYSQL create table queries. The integration is successful but when running the script, validation fails. I am getting this exception:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "--\000a-- Table structure for table `CANDIDATE`\000a--\000a\000aCREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CANDIDATE` (\000a  `CANDIDATE_ID` varchar(45) NOT NULL,\000a  `CANDIDATE` json NOT NULL,\000a  `PRIMARY_EMAIL_ID` varchar(100) NOT NULL,\000a  `PRIMARY_PHONE_NO` varchar(15) NOT NULL,\000a  `PD_SUBMITTED` varchar(1) NOT NULL,\000a  `ED_SUBMITTED` varchar(1) NOT NULL,\000a  `WE_SUBMITTED` varchar(1) NOT NULL,\000a  `TL_SUBMITTED` varchar(1) NOT NULL,\000a  `VA_SUBMITTED` varchar(1) NOT NULL,\000a  `CD_SUBMITTED` varchar(1) NOT NULL,\000a  `STATUS` varchar(20) NOT NULL,\000a  `EXTERNAL_CANDIDATE_ID` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,\000a  `LAST_UPDATED_BY` varchar(100) NOT NULL,\000a  `LAST_UPDATED` datetime NOT NULL,\000a  `CREATED_BY` varchar(100) NOT NULL,\000a  `DATE_CREATED` datetime NOT NULL,\000a  `ASSIGNED_TO` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,\000a  PRIMARY KEY (`CANDIDATE_ID`),\000a  UNIQUE [*]KEY `ID_UNIQUE` (`CANDIDATE_ID`),\000a  UNIQUE KEY `PRIMARY_PHONE_NO_UNIQUE` (`PRIMARY_PHONE_NO`),\000a  UNIQUE KEY `PRIMARY_EMAIL_ID_UNIQUE` (`PRIMARY_EMAIL_ID`),\000a  UNIQUE KEY `EXTERNAL_CANDIDATE_ID_UNIQUE` (`EXTERNAL_CANDIDATE_ID`),\000a  KEY `FKcqv0ciwdgiuo4e4h8g03wo5fe` (`ASSIGNED_TO`), CONSTRAINT `FKcqv0ciwdgiuo4e4h8g03wo5fe` FOREIGN KEY (`ASSIGNED_TO`) REFERENCES `INTERNAL_USER` (`USERNAME`)\000a)"; expected "("; SQL statement:
```

My SQL statement is as below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CANDIDATE` (
  `CANDIDATE_ID` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `CANDIDATE` json NOT NULL,
  `PRIMARY_EMAIL_ID` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `PRIMARY_PHONE_NO` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `PD_SUBMITTED` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `ED_SUBMITTED` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `WE_SUBMITTED` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `TL_SUBMITTED` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `VA_SUBMITTED` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `CD_SUBMITTED` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `STATUS` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `EXTERNAL_CANDIDATE_ID` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LAST_UPDATED_BY` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `LAST_UPDATED` datetime NOT NULL,
  `CREATED_BY` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `DATE_CREATED` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ASSIGNED_TO` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CANDIDATE_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ID_UNIQUE` (`CANDIDATE_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `PRIMARY_PHONE_NO_UNIQUE` (`PRIMARY_PHONE_NO`),
  UNIQUE KEY `PRIMARY_EMAIL_ID_UNIQUE` (`PRIMARY_EMAIL_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `EXTERNAL_CANDIDATE_ID_UNIQUE` (`EXTERNAL_CANDIDATE_ID`),
  KEY `FKcqv0ciwdgiuo4e4h8g03wo5fe` (`ASSIGNED_TO`), CONSTRAINT `FKcqv0ciwdgiuo4e4h8g03wo5fe` FOREIGN KEY (`ASSIGNED_TO`) REFERENCES `INTERNAL_USER` (`USERNAME`)
);
```

I tried executing this query against the h2 database by starting the applicaiton without flyway. When I run the whole query, I get the same error. But if I remove the lines from where the 'UNIQUE KEY' starts (keeping other syntax right; brackets, commas etc), I don't get an error and the statement executes successfully.

I saw a lot of references for the exception org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException for the cause 'expected identifier'. But I couldn't find any references for my error which says 'expected "("'

Can someone help.

Comment: You need to enable MySQL compatibility mode of H2 to use MySQL-specific declarations in this table definition. You also need to disable automatic configuration of testing databases by Spring Boot, otherwise your custom JDBC URL with compatibility settings will be ignored.

Comment: @EvgenijRyazanov this is my spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./data/local. Are you referring to this configuration:  spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./data/local;MODE=MySQL

Comment: I tried adding MODE=MySQL like here: spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./data/local;MODE=MySQL in my application.properties. I also tried adding SET MODE MySQL; as the beginning statement of my flyway migration .SQL script file. Both did not work